# All possible trips with multiple vehicles

Tags: python

Caveat - I am a complete newby to python and coding.

I wish to generate a list of lists using multiple vehicles and multiple trips.

```
vehicles = ["V1","V2"]
trips = [1, 2, 3]
```

The output required is:

```
[[(V1,1), (V1,2), (V1,3)],
 [(V1,1), (V1,2), (V2,3)],
 [(V1,1), (V2,2), (V2,3)],
 [(V1,1), (V2,2), (V1,3)],
 [(V2,1), (V2,2), (V2,3)],
 [(V2,1), (V2,2), (V1,3)],
 [(V2,1), (V1,2), (V1,3)],
 [(V2,1), (V1,2), (V2,3)]
]
```

i.e. 2^3 = 8 possible combinations of vehicles and trips.

I have tried:

```
# create empty lists to store the combinations
unique_comb = []

# get all permutations of vehicles with length of trips
permut = itertools.permutations(trips, len(vehicles))

# zip() is called to pair each permutation and longer list element into combination
for comb in permut:
    zipped = zip(comb, vehicles)
    unique_comb.append(list(zipped))

# print unique_comb list
print(unique_comb)
```

which yields:

```
[[(1, 'V1'), (2, 'V2')], 
[(1, 'V1'), (3, 'V2')], 
[(2, 'V1'), (1, 'V2')], 
[(2, 'V1'), (3, 'V2')], 
[(3, 'V1'), (1, 'V2')], 
[(3, 'V1'), (2, 'V2')]]
```

am I on the right track or way off? In the final solution I will be using 4 vehicles and 8 trips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're quite in the good direction ... and in the opposite. As the order of the trips keeps same `1,2,3`, you need to generate the `vehicles` variations not the `trips` one, then you'll `zip`

```
('V1', 'V1', 'V1')
('V1', 'V1', 'V2')
('V1', 'V2', 'V1')
('V1', 'V2', 'V2')
('V2', 'V1', 'V1')
('V2', 'V1', 'V2')
('V2', 'V2', 'V1')
('V2', 'V2', 'V2')
```

For that use `product(, repeat=3)` : `["V1", "V2"] x ["V1", "V2"] x ["V1", "V2"]`

```
import itertools

vehicles = ["V1", "V2"]
trips = [1, 2, 3]

unique_comb = []
for comb in itertools.product(vehicles, repeat=len(trips)):
    unique_comb.append(list(zip(comb, trips)))


[[('V1', 1), ('V1', 2), ('V1', 3)], [('V1', 1), ('V1', 2), ('V2', 3)], 
 [('V1', 1), ('V2', 2), ('V1', 3)], [('V1', 1),('V2', 2), ('V2', 3)], 
 [('V2', 1), ('V1', 2), ('V1', 3)], [('V2', 1), ('V1', 2), ('V2', 3)], 
 [('V2', 1), ('V2', 2), ('V1', 3)], [('V2', 1), ('V2', 2), ('V2', 3)]]
```